# Correct path for reading lines of a file

Tags: java, file, path

I am new in Java and I have a question regarding the method `readAlllines` for the class `Files`. The file `"Testfile.txt"` is saved in the same directory as my Java class `changeFiles`. I want to read the lines out of it.

Here is my example code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.util.List;



public class changeFiles {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        File temp =new File("Testfile.txt");
        Path p = temp.toPath();

        try{

        List<String> zeilen = Files.readAllLines(p);

        for(String line : zeilen){
            System.out.println(line);
        }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

}
```

Unfortunately, the method can't find the file. How do I get the correct path to my file in `readAllLines`?

Comment: The base path will be the directory from where you execute the program, not the class directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to get file from working directory, check yours printing this in some way

```
System.getProperty("user.dir")
```

Place `"Testfile.txt"` there, run and enjoy.

---

Another solution will be put folder when reading file using [`File(folder, file)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#File(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) constructor:

```
// imagine your file is placed in: c:\tmp\Testfile.txt
final String folder = "C:\\tmp\\";
File temp = new File(folder, "Testfile.txt");
```

---

Or maybe merge both:

```
final String folder = System.getProperty("user.dir");
File temp = new File(folder, "Testfile.txt");
```

Comment: BTW, using Paths.get is a more portable way of constructing a path.  For example: `Path p5 = Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.home"),"logs", "foo.log");` [requires Java 7+]

Answer (score 2):

Java class location is not the same as current directory.

For example current directory is something like:
`C:\Users\userName\project` (This is where txt file shoud be)

And java class is something like `C:\Users\userName\project\src\packageName\Java.java`

to find out what the current directory is you can run: `System.getProperty("user.dir")`